# there is a problem with <bdi> tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have known  Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm. But  I get confused a  when trying to test the code.

```html
<p dir="rtl">this is <bdo dir="rtl">APPLE</bdo>.</p>
<p dir="rtl">this is <bdi><bdo dir="rtl">APPLE</bdo></bdi>.</p>
```

I don`t understand why is the A here:
[image]

Comment: Why not? What do you expect it to show you? What are you trying to achieve? Why are you using the `bdo` tag inside the `bdi` tag? More information would be useful.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I just want to know why is the letter A on the front. I expect it should same as below. Because the 'dir ' is 'rtl'.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I just want to try to follow my idea.so, is it wrong that using the `bdo` tag inside the `bdi` tag?

Comment: I would discourage it yes, unless you have a very specific reason on why you'd want to do it?

Comment: no specific reason, I just want to understand the reason for that